# Cannot add SSR to already existing Spartacus project

Tags: angular, express, server-side-rendering, spartacus-storefront

I just tried to add SSR mode to my already existing Spartacus project by this command:

```
ng g @spartacus/schematics:add-ssr
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
    ✅️ Added 'ts-loader' into devDependencies
Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined
```

any idea how I can resolve this problem? What is more after trying to add everything manually and after running express server frontend cannot load properly ([I follow this documentation](https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/server-side-rendering-in-spartacus/)).

Comment: Hey, can you provide more details which version of Spartacus you are using?

Answer (score 3):

The recommended way to add SSR support to Spartacus is to use schematics. Please try it with following command:
`ng add @spartacus/schematics --ssr`

Ensure that your project meets all of the necessary prerequisites:
https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/schematics/#prerequisites

You can also try to remove `node_modules` folder and install all dependencies once again.

Comment: thanks for you answer. I'm using Spartacus 3.0.0 version also my local env meet these all prerequisites. I do not have any problems with running SSR mode on some others projects. Removing node_modules didn't help. In next answer I will put logs from ng add @spartacus/schematics --ssr command.

Comment: And which Angular CLI version are you using? Spartacus 3.0 officially supports ng 10 and ng 11 might be causing some of the issues you face.

Comment: Hi Marcin, I'm using 10.2.0 version of Angular CLI.

Comment: For both commands  run dev:ssr (from official Angular documentation) and  npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr (from Spartacus documenation) I got infinite loading of frontend without any result. In addition in the case of using first command also I'm getting "Unknown http response error: -1" logs

Answer (score 0):

Logs from `ng add @spartacus/schematics --ssr` command:

`ng add @spartacus/schematics --ssr Skipping installation: Package already installed ✅️ Added '@spartacus/core' into dependencies ✅️ Added '@spartacus/storefront' into dependencies ✅️ Added '@spartacus/assets' into dependencies ✅️ Added '@spartacus/styles' into dependencies ✅️ Added '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap' into dependencies ✅️ Added '@ng-select/ng-select' into dependencies ✅️ Added '@ngrx/store' into dependencies ✅️ Added '@ngrx/effects' into dependencies ✅️ Added '@ngrx/router-store' into dependencies ✅️ Added 'bootstrap' into dependencies ✅️ Added 'i18next' into dependencies ✅️ Added 'i18next-xhr-backend' into dependencies ✅️ Added '@angular/service-worker' into dependencies ✅️ Added '@angular/localize' into dependencies ✅️ Added 'ngx-infinite-scroll' into dependencies ✅️ Added 'angular-oauth2-oidc' into dependencies Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined`

Not sure if it's need but also I tried to run  `yarn build:core:lib` command:

`yarn build:core:lib yarn run v1.22.5 error Command "build:core:lib" not found. info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.`